# Vue.js CLI 3 - how can I create a vendor bundle for CSS/Sass?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

Using `@vue/cli` 3.x and I have modified my `vue.config.js` slightly. I want to have separate CSS files such as `app.css` and `vendor.css` (transpiled from Sass) - similar to how its configured to treat the JavaScript. I am unsure how to set the proper config to achieve this. Am I loading my files incorrectly? Missing the mark entirely?

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // [...]
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          shared: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendor',
            enforce: true,
            chunks: 'all',
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

My where build results in...

```
dist
├── css
|   └── app.css
├── js
|   ├── app.js
|   └── vendor.js
```

`app.css` includes **all** I've imported through my `node_modules`. My style import is as follows in my main `App.vue` component...

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '../node_modules/minireset.css/minireset.sass';
</style>

// [...]
```

My desired result is the following structure, where the "vendor" CSS/Sass is extracted out...

```
dist
├── css
|   ├── app.css
|   └── vendor.css
├── js
|   ├── app.js
|   └── vendor.js
```

---

I've looked into the [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) where the first sentences states the following...

> This plugin extracts CSS into separate files

But I've found no examples of how to do it idiomatically in the Vue.js ecosystem. I've also tried to add the following to my `vue.config.js`, but nothing seems to take effect...

```
module.exports = {
  // [...]
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: 'css/[name].css',
      chunkFilename: 'css/[name].css',
    },
  },
};
```

---

I've also found what should have been a home run explanation in the [Vue SSR Guide | CSS Management](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#importing-styles-from-dependencies), but it uses `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` which has been deprecated in favor of [webpack.optimize. SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/), throwing a build error...

> Error: webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin has been removed, please
>   use config.optimization.splitChunks instead.

Comment: Though this question is answered, I largely consider the current solution a workaround. I've opened an issue against the project which hopefully will gain some attention in the future https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3252

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vue.config.js` also lets you use a `chainWebpack` method. It might be preferable because it allows you to modify the vue-cli config. Using `configureWebpack` overwrites the default config entirely, which might be part of the problem in regards to getting yours to work with Sass.

<strike>This config is for pure CSS only, but is fairly similar to what you have.</strike>

Just tried this with some Sass embedded into some style blocks, and it breaks up the vendor css from the app css.

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack(config) {
        config
            .output.chunkFilename('[name].bundle.js').end()
            .optimization.splitChunks({
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendorStyles: {
                        name: 'vendor',
                        test(module) {
                            return (
                                /node_modules/.test(module.context) &&
                                // do not externalize if the request is a CSS file
                                !/\.css$/.test(module.request)
                            );
                        },
                        chunks: 'all',
                        enforce: true
                    }
                }
            });
    }
};
```

**Update**

It's also necessary to pull out your `@import '../node_modules/minireset.css/minireset.sass';` and other import statements out of the `style` block and put it in the `script` block of your vue component:

```
// your component file
<script>
    import "minireset.css/minireset.sass";
    // rest of script
</script>
```

The file will still be imported and used in your style block below.

My exports include a vendor.[hash].css and an app.[hash].css file. The app file has the content of the style blocks. Since I kept my test app simple and to your use case, the vendor file contains only the style info from minireset:

```
// vendor.[hash].css
/*! minireset.css v0.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/jgthms/minireset.css */blockquote,body,dd,dl,dt,fieldset,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,html,iframe,legend,li,ol,p,pre,textarea,ul{margin:0;padding:0}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:400}ul{list-style:none}button,input,select,textarea{margin:0}html{box-sizing:border-box}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:inherit}audio,embed,iframe,img,object,video{height:auto;max-width:100%}iframe{border:0}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}td,th{padding:0;text-align:left}
```

Git repo of vue app [here](https://github.com/GenericDeveloper14/vue-preprocessor-bundles). The import of the sass file is in `HelloWorld.vue`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm still getting a single CSS file with everything in there. Is there any other important details you've left out? If you could whip up a minimal github repo I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: Added an update. I overlooked that my import statements were occurring in my script block instead of the style block.

Comment: Dude, nice! Yes, this indeed works. Though, I am not a _total_ fan of the workaround for one reason at the moment. So with this trivial example, I can import `minreset` and chunk it out to a `vendor.css` file. However, I need to set a sass variable before my imports, which affects my further imports regarding pathing. I know that's out of scope for this question and I'm still going to likely accept your answer, that's just my only hang up. Otherwise this is working well. I'm still craving to be able to do it in a `<style>` block. Maybe that's wishful thinking at this point!

Comment: I tried keeping the import scripts in the style block and it constantly backfires. There might be a way to configure how/when scss is converted to `css` from the style blocks but I haven't seen a way to do it.

Comment: Yep, something is amiss with how the style imports are handled. This works for me, I figured out the variable thing on my end. I still consider this a workaround, but hopefully this becomes trivial in the future. Perhaps when `@next` is generally available things will be different. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help!

Comment: Just an FYI I've opened up an issue on their repo we can track should future core changes clarify or support what's happened here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3252

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to your webpack config (per [the docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/guide/webpack.md)):

```
// vue.config.js

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // [...]
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css'
      })
    ],
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          shared: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendor',
            enforce: true,
            chunks: 'all',
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

However, this [may not work with single file components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1220). In order to get that working you might have to use [`vue-loader@next`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/tree/next)

Comment: Adding the plugin does not make it active. You would need to add it as a loader that is activated after it passes some test, like `/\.css$/`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this as well and I indeed spit out two files, but they are duplicated with all the app and vendor styles. I've looked at the `next` branch, but it's been inactive for almost a year - unsure how I feel about that

Answer (score 0):

I have used once this plugin and I believe it does what you want to achieve: https://github.com/teamable-software/css-chunks-html-webpack-plugin